# MySQL consuming a lot of CPU

Tags: mysql, database, database-administration, easy-engine

I’m having trouble with a new server I installed the Optimized configuration for Ubuntu server with EasyEngine of VirtuBox

when migrating my website with template newspaper. the cpu consumption is very high,

follow the prints
    [MYSQLTUNER REPORT][1]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B57hr.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj8r2.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAbHG.png)

[MYSQL TUNER RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAbHG.png)

I have a database with more than 400 thousand posts
my server is

Intel Core i7-6700K CPU
HDD 250 GB SSD
HDD 250 GB SSD
RAM 16 GB DDR4-2133 PC4-17000
RAM 16 GB DDR4-2133 PC4-17000

with easyengine + rediscache + wordpress

plugins we use

Redis Object Drop-In Cache v1.3.8 by Till Krüss Plugins:
Advanced Custom Fields PRO v5.6.6 by Elliot Condon (Active)
Custom fields display v1.1 by Shambhu Prasad Patnaik (Inactive)
Duplicate Post v3.2.2 by Enrico Battocchi (Inactive)
Export media with selected content v1.0 by Joost de Keijzer (Inactive)
Facebook Instant Articles & Google AMP Pages by PageFrog v1.0.9 by PageFrog Team (Inactive)
Fast Velocity Minify v2.3.4 by Raul Peixoto (Inactive)
Google Analytics Dashboard for WP (GADWP) v5.3.5 by ExactMetrics (Active)
Google News Editors Picks Feed Generator v2.0 by Peoples_Pundit (Inactive)
Google News Sitemap v1.0.11 by Andrea Pernici (Active)
Inline Related Posts v2.2.0 by IntellyWP (Active)
Insert Post Ads v1.0.6 by WPBeginner (Inactive)
Mashshare Share Buttons v3.4.4 by René Hermenau (Inactive)
Nginx Helper v1.9.11 by rtCamp (Active)
Octolooks Scrapes v1.4.3 by Octolooks (Inactive)
OneSignal Push Notifications v1.16.7 by OneSignal (Active)
Page Visit Counter v4.0.4 by Multidots (Inactive)
Redis Object Cache v1.3.8 by Till Krüss (Active)
Smush v2.8.0.1 by WPMU DEV (Active)
SSL Insecure Content Fixer v2.7.0 by WebAware (Inactive)
tagDiv AMP v1.1 by tagDiv (Active)
tagDiv Composer v2.1 by tagDiv (Active)
tagDiv Mobile Theme v1.1 by tagDiv (Inactive)
tagDiv Multi-Purpose v2.0 by tagDiv (Active)
tagDiv Newsletter v1.0 by tagDiv (Active)
TagDiv Social Counter v4.2 by tagDiv (Active)
tagDiv Speed ​​Booster v4.9.1 by tagDiv (Active)
WordPress Importer v0.6.4 by wordpressdotorg (Active)
WP-Polls v2.73.7 by Lester 'GaMerZ' Chan (Inactive)
WP Awesome Import & Export v2.6.1 by ddeveloper (Inactive)
WPBakery Page Builder v5.4.5 by Michael M - WPBakery.com (Active)
WP Easy Gallery v4.2.1 by HahnCreativeGroup (Inactive)
WP Remove Category Base v1.0 by Ezra Verheijen (Active)
WP Responsive Menu v3.0.3 by MagniGenie (Inactive)
Yoast SEO v7.3 by Team Yoast (Active)

with little access the consumption of cpu is a load average: 7.56, 3.43, 4.81

Thank you in advance for your attention.

```
[1]: https://pastebin.com/sTrBTDtY
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming - unless you manage to identify particular pieces of code, which you can't optimise yourself. DBA or serverfault sister sites of SO can offer you more help in resolving database / system administration issues.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Sorry we won't be too much help on this one. Agreeing we should get this moved over to dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @KleberSilva If you could post text results of ulimit -a, SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; and SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; in depth analysis of your MySQL instance would be possible.  Thanks.

Comment: @KleberSilva Please look at your dba.stackexchange.com Question 218660 for Suggestions posted about 10/9/2018 to improve your response time.  Let us know your progress in a couple of weeks, please.  Thanks